# Redundant authorization action in API Store for API restricted by role

Tags: wso2

I'm using SWO2 API Manager 1.4.0. When user logs in to API Store and opens API with visibility "Restricted By Roles", it asks user's credentials again.
It happens when `Swagger` loads `api-doc.json` from

`/registry/resource/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/api-docs/ApiName-Version/api-doc.json`

and receives code 401 in answer.

The question is: how should I configure API Manager to make it use user's credentials for any calls to Governance Registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We give anonymous permissions for the swagger json resource when creating the API. So I am not sure how this issue is appearing to you. Can you please check what is the permission assigned for the  api-doc.json? This can be checked by accessing the resource through registry browser in management console and expanding the Permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped! But AFAIU for **'Restricted By Roles'** API's api-doc.json document is visible only to admin and specified roles. I've checked it as you suggested, created API with visibility 'Restricted By Roles' and specified 'subscriber' role. After it its swagger doc is visible only to 'admin' and 'subscriber' roles. Btw thanks!

Comment: But this is something we fixed for the release, after getting this same problem you explained. Thats why I can't understand how is it still getting to you. I downloaded a fresh pack from OT and tested this scenario. But I couldn't reproduce the issue. I will check further. Thanks